# Does Z3_ast reference counting count references outside Z3?

Tags: z3

In Z3 there are 2 modes: automatic reference counting and manual.

I understand how manual ref counting works. Thanks to example.

**But how does Z3 know when to delete AST node in automatic ref-counting case?**
Since Z3_ast is a struct from C language => it is impossible to track all assignments and usages of Z3_ast outside Z3 after it was created.

**Or Z3 track references inside Z3 only?** That is no updates to ref counters are made if you do for example: ast1 = ast2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatic mode uses a very simple policy. Whenever an AST is returned to the user, Z3 stores it on a stack `S` and increments its reference counter.
When the `Z3_push` function is executed, Z3 saves the size of the stack `S`. When the matching `Z3_pop` is executed, the size of the stack `S` is restored, and the reference counter of the ASTs popped from the stack is decremented. 
This mode is very easy to use, but it has a main problem: memory consumption. For example, if `Z3_push` and `Z3_pop` are not used, then all ASTs created by the user will never be deleted.